# Passing format in a SQL UDF

Tags: sql, casting, teradata

I'm working on making a simple SQL UDF, to cast from char/varchar to time.
Since it is supposed to be something generic, I wanted the user to specify the format his input is, so I could just use something like

```
cast(user_time as time(0) format user_format)
```

but it doesn't work.
I'd like to know if it is possible to use a format as an UDF parameter and if it is, how it should be used in this cast. I could break it apart to read the format and make the time match, but I'd rather avoid it if there's a simpler way to do it.

Just to clarify, I'm using Teradata 14, and I have to use SQL, so an UDF in C is not really an option for me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You would have to use dynamic SQL in your UDF.  EDIT: Not sure if you can use dynamic sql in a udf, maybe only in stored procedures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass a FORMAT as a parameter to a CAST.

You might be able to do this using TO_TIMESTAMP instead, but why do you need a UDF for that?

```
myUDF('12:34:45', 'hh:mi:ss')
```

is not much shorter than an old style Teradata CAST:

```
hh:mi:ss' (time(0), FORMAT 'hh:mi:ss')
```

Comment: it's company policy. some users who are going to use it aren't really familiar with teradata or any kind of programming, so we're trying to make everything as user friendly as possible, even if it means hiding just a to_timestamp behind a UDF. And thank you for answering my question